# Filter after multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, filter

I have a modal that serves to filter items based on filters, my problem is that I can give them as filter only the title while I would also like to give author and year for different text input.

This is my modal.ts function for filtering only the title (I want to also filter title, author and years)

```
filterItems() {
     this.filteritems = this.items.filter(item =>item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1);
}
```

This is the example of my json:

```
[
 {
   "id":"1",
   "author": "Chinua Achebe",
   "country": "Nigeria",
   "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
   "language": "English",
   "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
   "pages": 209,
   "title": "Things Fall Apart",
   "year": 1958
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat all fields which you want to filter by and test the concatenated string:

```
this.filteritems = this.items.filter(item 
  => (item.title + item.author + item.year).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1);})
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability I'd say use something like this:

```
filterItems() {
  const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase();

  this.filterItems = this.items.filter(item =>
       item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    || item.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
    || item.years == searchTerm)
}
```

This approach is very readable as we can see exactly what are we filtering by.

Also, here's the documentation for [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Comment: i have 3 input text, i can apply only one ng model in this metod

Comment: i have searchTerm, searchAuthor, searchYears

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
// Filter input fields object
var filterData = {
  "title" : "Things You dont know",
  "author": "Alpha Beta",
  "year": 1953
};

// Data object
var items = [
 {
   "id":"1",
   "author": "Chinua Achebe",
   "country": "Nigeria",
   "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
   "language": "English",
   "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
   "pages": 209,
   "title": "Things Fall Apart",
   "year": 1958
 },{
   "id":"2",
   "author": "Alpha Beta",
   "country": "Nigeria",
   "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
   "language": "English",
   "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
   "pages": 209,
   "title": "Things You dont know",
   "year": 1953
 },{
   "id":"3",
   "author": "Author Name",
   "country": "Nigeria",
   "imageLink": "images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
   "language": "English",
   "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
   "pages": 209,
   "title": "Welcome to JavaScript",
   "year": 1947
 }
];

// Logic to check for all the three filters data and give the output
var filteredItems = items.filter(obj => {
   if ((obj.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterData.title.toLowerCase()) > -1) &&
       (obj.author.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterData.author.toLowerCase()) > -1) &&
       (obj.year == filterData.year)) {
       return obj;
     }
});

console.log(filteredItems);
```

**Note :** As per OP, I am assuming that all the three fields (Title, Author & year) are mandatory fields.